# Camel XML spliting multiple elements with XPath

Tags: apache-camel

I'm pooling a directory to read and parser XML file.

XML sample:

```
<bookstore>
 <book>
  <title lang="en">The Origins of Totalitarianism‎</title>
  <author>Hannah Arendt</author>
  <price>30.00</price>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <price>29.99</price>
 </book>
 <author name="Hannah Arendt">
  <age>29</age>
  </author>
 <author name="J K. Rowling">
  <age>29</age>
 </author>
</bookstore>
```

I can split on element node using `<xpath>/bookstore/book</xpath>`, but how can I read more one node, like `<book>` and `<author>`

```
<from
 uri="file:/tmp/ready"/>
 <split>
  <xpath>/bookstore/book</xpath>
  <to uri="direct:process-xml-position" />
</split>
```

Version `Apache Camel 2.20.1`

Comment: Are you looking to get a single result list with both `bookstore/book` and `bookstore/author` elements? In which case you can just combine the two paths with |

Comment: The process from each node is independently, each one have another router. The book/author isn't real domain.

Answer (score 0):

So, I find out that one split for node element works.

```
<from
 uri="file:/tmp/ready"/>
 <split>
  <xpath>/bookstore/book</xpath>
  <to uri="direct:mock/>
 </split>
 <split>
  <xpath>/bookstore/author</xpath>
  <to uri="direct:mock/>
 </split>
</from>
```